# File Retrieval from java code

Tags: java, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I am trying to retrieve files from ftp.I am getting following exception.
Sometimes concurrent access to same file can be case.My firewall is turn off.

**My question is
how can get ride of this exception, because it can not download necassary files, my program does not make its work**

My download code:

```
    public boolean downloadFile(String sourceFilePath, String destinationDirPath, String newFileName)
            throws IllegalStateException {

//      final FTPClient client = this.getClient();
        FileOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            // The remote filename to be downloaded.
            String filename = new File(sourceFilePath).getName();
            // Downloads the selected file to the C drive
            output = new FileOutputStream(destinationDirPath + File.separator + newFileName);
            this.cd(new File(sourceFilePath).getParent());
            // Download file from FTP server
            boolean result = client.retrieveFile(filename, output);
            log.trace("File is downloaded from server:" + filename + ", to destination:"+newFileName);
            return result;
        }
        // Indicate that an exception is occurred while downloading file
        catch (Exception ioe) {
            throw new FileTransferException("Could not download file", ioe);
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                try {
                    // trying to close FileOutputStream
                    output.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    log.warn("Error closing writer to file:"+newFileName, e);
                }
                output = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is the stack trace:

```
Exception during data transfer, closing data connection socket
    java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnection.transfer(IODataConnection.java:289)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.IODataConnection.transferToClient(IODataConnection.java:161)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.command.impl.RETR.execute(RETR.java:166)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.impl.DefaultFtpHandler.messageReceived(DefaultFtpHandler.java:210)
        at org.apache.ftpserver.listener.nio.FtpHandlerAdapter.messageReceived(FtpHandlerAdapter.java:61)
        at
```

Comment: You haven't said what the exception is, or asked an actual question.

Comment: Show us the initialization of `client` too. Did you do a connection ? Are you sure this function isn't called by two threads ?

Comment: You might need to use PASV mode depending on the firewalls/NAT in your way.

Comment: What is client ? Can you show its code ?

Comment: @Vivek from the tags I guess it's [this one](http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). But there can be so many misuses in the code we don't see...

Comment: Also, if this is a low-level networking problem, it may be platform-specific. Please indicate the platform you are running (OS version, JDK version).

Comment: @dystroy  you are right this is Commons Net FTPClient.I have a class that is responsible for FTp Operations(cd, connect, upload,etc).

Comment: I am creating an instance of that class, then calling functions like download.In the connect part of code I am creating FTPClient instance.JDK 1.6.23 Operating system is Windows XP.But I know that in Server 2008 it is also producible

Comment: Sorry, I sent wrong piece of code.Download code is updated